# Want Javascript run while loop infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, css, while-loop, settimeout

I want the Javascript code can manipulate some object in html infinitely,

But, I can only use `setTimeout("function()", 0)` and can't use `while(1)`

**examples**:

`while`: https://gist.github.com/Asoul/e5dd3bd38eef4ca239cb

`setTimeout` : https://gist.github.com/Asoul/bda34fa2f70e4077ec12

I don't know why the `while(1)` can't work on my chrome

`SetTimeout` can work sometimes, but if there are many `setTimeout` in my code or some unknown reasons, it will lag.

**example**: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b00902036/run_neo/run_neo.html

(Use up, left, right to play. I tried hard to avoid lags, but sometimes it still happen.)

I want use pure CSS, not canvas, and want the game can play without lags.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Is it that you want to manipulate DOM whenever some property changes??

Comment: I want to change the css attribute(top, left), to move the div.

Comment: @elclanrs : Thanks! I'll use it :)

Comment: If you are trying to animate the div, you could do this easily with css3 transitions.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, but there is something called "WebWorkers" which gives a touch of multithreading environment. It is limited though.

Comment: @ArunAravind : I have used CSS3 transitions, but it seems can't stop at anytime, I don't know how to solve it, so I change top and left instead. Do you have better advice? :)

Comment: OK! I'll try webworkers! Thanks :)

Comment: NO no webworkers won't do any good in this situation. That was intended for the comment "javascript is single-threaded".

Comment: ofcourse you have better control while doing with css. put up a class 'animate' and write your animation rules there.  Whenever you want to animate the div, add this class using javascript. It will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason you cannot use `while` is because javascript is ***single-threaded***. If you use `while(1)`, the function will never exit and all other interactions are frozen.

> SetTimeout can work sometimes, but if there are many setTimeout in my
>   code or some unknown reasons, it will lag.

This is also because of single-threaded nature of javascript, if there is a function taking long time to complete, it will dominate the main thread.

> want the game can play without lags.

You need to avoid long-running operation inside ***all of your functions***. If you cannot avoid that, try using `setTimeout` to split a long-running operation into many pieces. 
For example: if you have a for-loop processing 100 records, you could split it into 10 separate iterations.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Asoul/5544704767a7199b89e5
but it can work on my chrome, like multithread.